# Out of range in a list inside a list

Tags: python, list

I have a "out of range" probem. This is the code:

```
S = []
while( len(edges) != 0):
   e = random.randint(0,len(edges)-1)
   k = random.randint(0,1)
   Vert = edges[e][k]
   print(Vert)
   S.append(Vert)           

   for i in range(len(edges)):
       for j in range(2):
           if edges[i][j] == Vert:
              edges.pop([i][0])
if edges[i][j] == Vert:



IndexError: list index out of range
```

edges is an list like following:

```
[(0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Any ideia how to fix?

I have also tried the "in" sytanx like

```
S = []  # Dominating Set

while( len(edges) != 0):
    e = random.randint(0,len(edges)-1)
    k = random.randint(0,1)
    Vert = edges[e][k]
    print(Vert)
    S.append(Vert)           

    for i in range(len(edges)):
 
            if Vert in edges[i]:
                edges.pop([i])
```

But get the error

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The ideia of the code is find the dominating set in a graph and the algorithm goes as follow

```
#    First we have to initialize a set ‘S’ as empty
#    Take any edge ‘e’ of the graph connecting the vertices ( say A and B )
#    Add one vertex between A and B ( let say A ) to our set S
#    Delete all the edges in the graph connected to A
#    Go back to step 2 and repeat, if some edge is still left in the graph
#    The final set S is a Dominant Set of the graph
```

After some thinking I did another verison but still got the out of range error:

```
    size = len(edges)
    i = 0
    while( size != i):
        for j in range(2):
            if edges[i][j] == Vert:
                edges.pop([i][0])
                size = size-1
                i = 0
            else:
                i = i+1
```

Comment: @OldBill nothing because the error doesn´t do 1 loop

Comment: @OldBill Is, its a list I know but that's as nothing to do with the problem here...

Comment: @OldBill Thank you for saying the errors that I get when I literally put them in the question.... I'm asking how can I fix, not what are the errors

Comment: We can probably help you further if you show what the output should be

Comment: @OldBill no need to be rude, this is a community to help everybody not to judge them

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing in the operation of `edges.pop([i][j])` is actually you're creating a new list `[i]`, and then trying to access element `[j]` of that one-length list.

Comment: Yes but how do I fix then?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Could you please detail what the aim of the code is?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(edges)):
    for j in range(2):
        if edges[i][j] == Vert:
            edges.pop([i][j])
```

When you call `edges.pop()`, that makes the list smaller, and the outer for loop `for i in range(len(edges))` will try to iterate over an element that isn't there anymore.

Comment: Yes but how do I fix then?

Comment: @OldBill removes the tuple, I have updated the question with all the information

Comment: @OldBill I'm sorry but I think you are not understanding it right. The pop removes and element, with i and j will remove the all 2 element tuple

Comment: @JohnGordon I have tried pop((1,2)) and doens´t workbut the pop([1][2]) works... and also the error is in if :) not the pop. Trying your way give the error TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @GoncaloFreitas Yeah, ignore what I wrote.  `pop()` takes an integer index, not an actual element value.  I plead lack of coffee.  :-)

Comment: But in any case, you're still passing the wrong argument to pop. What `[i][j]`  actually does is 1) make a one-element list `[i]`, and then 2) index into that list at position `[j]`.  The `[j]` is worthless here.  If j is anything other than 0 it will cause an error, because `[i]` obviously has a length of one.

Comment: @JohnGordon Now you are rigth I updated the code with 0 but still give the error in the IF